# How to get post type and month/year before while loop for date.php file

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

I am trying to create a `date.php` file for archives for some custom post types. I am using a while loop to get the posts:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

I want to customize the `date.php` file such that it caters to the specific post types that the archive page is for e.g. creating page titles such as "*Custom Post Type Name* Archives".

Is there any function where I can get the post type that the archive is referring to BEFORE the while loop? And also for monthly/ yearly archives, is there any way to get the month/date of the posts before the loop begins?